# assign a value to a text box using java script

Tags: javascript, html

I hava just a simple issue .

I wanna assign a value to a text box , but not as a string , as Java script function .

I will give you simple example :

```
     <input type="text" value="exam">//  here i assign the value as a string .





    <input type="text" value=functionx() >  // functionx is a java script function that        
          will assign a value to the text box.

     <script > function functionx(){return 'exam';}</script>
```

now after this simple example , my question is : how can i assign a value to the text box using java script function ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to assign it in the script, you cannot call a function in the value attribute of the html.

Try this:

```
var text = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0]; // would be better if you have a ID
text.value = functionx();
```

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JVXZy/)**

My suggestion is to give a `id` to the input (like `<input id="input_id" type="text" value="exam">`) and then use `getElementByID` instead in my example.

In this case it could look like [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JVXZy/1/).

Comment: that is perfect ; yes  , dont worry a bout ID , in my code of course there is ID , but this is example ,you know. this is right answer , thanx.